# Why is controller reloaded with each navigation

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a settings page, which updates some data on the server, and upon success, updates the scope model.

The problem is that with each navigation the controller function executes, thus overriding the changes with some init values.

Is there a way to avoid this re-loading with each navigation?
alternativaley, is there a technique to retain state of data within Angular's tool set?

Comment: Why doesn't the controller load the settings from the server in the first place? That way, every time you would navigate to the page, you would see the letest values, even if you or someone elese modified them from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature of controllers. What you're looking for is an Angular *service*.

You should use controllers to manage (ephemeral) UI state; for retaining "business logic" state on the client, services are more suitable.